# Why does "#define WC(p) L#p" not work in GCC and Clang?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang

Demo program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define WC(p) L#p

int main()
{
    wcout << WC(XXX);
}
```

It runs perfectly fine on Visual C++, but fails to compile on both Clang and GCC on Linux. Errors (clang 3.4, Linux):

- file.cpp:8:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'L'
- file.cpp:4:15: note: expanded from macro 'WC'

Why does it fail? How do I create a wide-char string literal using C defines? Such ability would drastically reduce code duplication in my case.

Comment: MSVC preprocessor is non-standard: it works on a stream of characters, not a stream of tokens as it should. Classic example: `#define N(x) -x`, then `N(N(1));` produces an error in MSVC because it expands to `--1` (a decrement), not `- - 1` (two unary negations). GCC and clang are correct: just putting `L` token and `"xyz"` token next to each other shouldn't produce a single `L"xyz"` token; you need a token-pasting `##` operator for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor operates on a sequence of tokens.

In the definition of the macro `WC(p)`, there are three tokens in the replacement list: `L`, `#`, and `p`. The `#` is an operator, of course, which "stringizes" the following token. The important thing is that `L` is a token by itself. The result of macro replacement on `WC(XXX)` is *two* tokens: `L` and `"XXX"`.

A wide string literal, on the other hand, is a *single* token. Regardless of the spelling of the macro replacement list, two separate tokens, where one is `L` and the other is a narrow string literal, do *not* constitute a wide string literal. It's the same as `L "XXX"`, with a space.

You need to paste together the two tokens into a single token in order to get a wide string literal. This suggests the following solution:

```
#define WC(p) L ## #p
```

**Edit**: However, as pointed out in the comments, this might not work either because the language does not guarantee that `#` will be evaluated before `##`. We have to force the preprocessor to convert `p` to a string first, *then* paste the tokens:

```
#define CONCAT(x, y) x ## y
#define WC(p) CONCAT(L, #p)
```

Now `WC(XXX)` will first undergo macro replacement to yield `CONCAT(L, "XXX")`. Then further macro replacement yields the single token `L"XXX"`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think this still isn't valid. The order in which `##` and `#` are performed is unspecified, so a preprocessor is permitted to attempt to concatenate `L` and `#`, and issue an error message because `L#` is not a valid token. Another level of macro indirection is needed: `#define WC(p) CONCAT(L, #p)` and `#define CONCAT(x, y) x ## y`.

Comment: @hvd I stand corrected. You should write an answer, so I can delete mine.

Comment: I commented on your answer because the gist of it is right, and your explanation is almost certainly clearer than mine would be, so feel free to edit it into your answer.